# bootstrap blog template is not working as intended

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I am using this: http://www.bootply.com/86704
  The problem is, that it covers all my web page from top to bottom.I want to use this in my site, but under the header, so I can scroll and see all content of the site.What property needs to be modified and how ?

Answer (score 0):

This is rough but you can just

- Remove height: 100%; from html, body in your styles
- Set height: 150px; to .wrapper class in your styles

This would shrink it down to 150px in height, and you could just put whole content of .wrapper class (including) to your website where ever you need